# How to send header in postman via Php

Tags: php, rest, postman

I am creating web service and i want to send "header" in postman via Php,How can i do this ? How can i send and get header using postman in php ? I tried with following code but i am getting response "please send access token",How can i fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
$tokens=apache_request_headers();
        $token=$tokens['access_token'];
        if(empty($token))
        {
                    $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Message" => "Please enter access token");
                    header("content-type:application/json");
                    $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
                    echo $response; 
        }
        else
        {
                //your code
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tab called headers you can add header in there.

[image]

If you're using fastCGI then headers will come as camelcase so you need to use it as:

```
$token=$tokens['Access_token'];
```

[image]

Comment: its not working, still i am not getting "Access_token" which i pass in postman header

Comment: print_r($tokens) and see the results.

Comment: i am getting following response

Array
(
    [Content-Length] => 11
    [Content-Type] => text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [Connection] => close
    [Cookie] => xxxxxxxxx
    [Host] => xxxxx.in
    [Origin] => xxxxxxxx
    [User-Agent] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [X-Forwarded-For] => xxxxxxx
)

Comment: as you can see there is no "access_token" in array

Comment: Only possible reason is you're not passing it correctly.. otherwise apache_request_headers() will get all the results.. and print_r should show your custom header..

Comment: Thanks for reply but can you show me proper screenshot so i can see my mistake

Comment: Added the complete screenshot.. this is postman extension in chrome.. what are you using to submit the request?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

at the top of the PHP code in the web api